global.asax Parser Error Could not load type "HttpApplication.Global"
Has anyone ever dealt with this obscure error regarding global.asax? From what I've been able to gather in my research is that its likely an IIS thing. Because my app usually publishes to my web server but now it only renders locally.
Error screenshot:

I've tried using CodeFile instead of Codebehind, but then it won't compile my codebehind classes.
I've also cleared my bin and rebuilt the solution several times to get it to compile on my live server.
Let me know what you've tried, Willing to share the rest of my code if you have time to walk through it with me.
The errorMessage:
Server Error in '/' Application.
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'WorldsStrongestProgrammer2024App.Global'.

Source Error:


Line 1:  <%@ Application CodeBehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="WorldsStrongestProgrammer2024App.Global" Language="C#" %>

Source File: /global.asax    Line: 1

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4700.0


You can't just out of the blue change the CodeFile to CodeBehind UNLESS you are using a asp.net web site "application" as opposed to a asp.net web site.
For a web site, you don't have a project file, and go file->open web site. And with a web site, then IIS is compiling the source code which is included at publish time.
If you using an "application", then at publish time the source code is compiled, and the code behind pages are NOT published to the server (they are stripped out, and hence IIS is not doing the site compile for you).
So, by changing a page from CodeFile to CodeBehind, then that assumes an "application". And this means that the site (IIS) is now not doing the site compile of code, and as noted, in fact your source code files are not even published to the server.
The once exception to this rule is of course code placed in the app_code folder. In that case, when using an "application", then I of course don't use app_code, and create a folder called MyCode. The reasons are many, but one of course is that Rosslyn compiler extensions may well not be available on the web server you are publishing to. So, then you want the site compile to occur at publish time.
However, when using your own MyCode file in place of app_code (which you should do), then each class and code file (or code module if using vb.net) placed in that folder will need the build action to be set manually.
That would be this build action:

So, you can't out of the blue start changing page directives, unless you change them all, and now assume you going to use a asp.net web site "application", which of course means that if you change one line of code for a given page, then a full re-publish is required each time. So, while the "web site" option was often used for ease of updates, you lose many project features, such as having multiple projects in one, better resolution of assembly references, and perhaps top in this list is that references to .dll's and assemblies (even Nugget packages) .dll's are NOT placed in the bin folder. This means you can clean project, and even delete the bin folder, and clean out stuff that builds up over time, and it is at build time that all assemblies are resolved, and then copied to the bin folder. (hence you NEVER reference a .dll and assembly from the bin folder).
So, if you using a "web site", then all your pages will have CodeFile.
If you using a "web site application", then all your pages will have CodeBehind.
If you are in the process of converting the "web site" to a "web site application", of which I highly recommend, then you should not have a mix of both types of page directive. They should all be one way, and the same.
It is possible at some point in time you were using File->open web site (this is how you open a asp.net web site, and then out of blue you started opening a project file (File->open project->select .sln file). In general, you can't just start using the project file if that site was a "web site" as opposed to a "web site application".
So, I would consider re-naming the app_code file, or not using it. Regardless, you could try setting the build option of the code files in app_code to "compile" and see if that helps.
So, how this works depends on what type of project you are working with, but you most certainly cannot out of the blue just start changing the page directive from CodeFile to CodeBehind. Of course, if you are migrating the web site to an "application", then yes, you are to change CodeFile to CodeBehind.
How to convert a web site to application is outlined here:
How to convert ASP.NET website to ASP.NET web application
